# Numba on nested Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numba

***Setup***

I have the following two implementations of a matrix-calculation:

1. The first implementation uses a `matrix of shape (n, m)` and the calculation is repeated in a for-loop for `repetition`-times:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def foo():
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(1, m):

            _deleteA = (
                        matrix[i, j] +
                        #some constants added here
            )
            _deleteB = (
                        matrix[i, j-1] +
                        #some constants added here
            )
            matrix[i, j] = min(_deleteA, _deleteB)

    return matrix

repetition = 3
for x in range(repetition):
    foo()
```

2. The second implementation avoids the extra for-loop and, hence, includes `repetition = 3` into the matrix, which is then of `shape (repetition, n, m)`:

```py
@jit
def foo():
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(1, m):

            _deleteA = (
                        matrix[:, i, j] +
                        #some constants added here
            )
            _deleteB = (
                        matrix[:, i, j-1] +
                        #some constants added here
            )
            matrix[:, i, j] = np.amin(np.stack((_deleteA, _deleteB), axis=1), axis=1)

    return matrix
```

***Questions***

Regarding both implementations, I discovered two things regarding their performance with `%timeit` in iPython.

1. The first implementation profits hugely from `@jit`, while the second does not at all (28ms vs. 25sec in my testcase). *Can anybody imagine why `@jit` does not work anymore with a numpy-array of shape `(repetition, n, m)`?*

***Edit***

I moved the former second question to [an extra post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055257/performance-decreases-with-increasing-nesting-of-array-elements) since asking multiple questions is concidered bad SO-style.

The question was:

2. When neglecting `@jit`, the first implementation is still a lot faster (same test-case: 17sec vs. 26sec). *Why is numpy slower when working on three instead of two dimensions?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your setup is here, but I re-wrote your example slightly:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

#@jit(nopython=True)
def foo(matrix):
    n, m = matrix.shape
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(1, m):

            _deleteA = (
                        matrix[i, j] #+
                        #some constants added here
            )
            _deleteB = (
                        matrix[i, j-1] #+
                        #some constants added here
            )
            matrix[i, j] = min(_deleteA, _deleteB)

    return matrix

foo_jit = jit(nopython=True)(foo)
```

and then timings:

```
m = np.random.normal(size=(100,50))

%timeit foo(m)  # in a jupyter notebook
# 2.84 ms ± 54.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit foo_jit(m)  # in a jupyter notebook
# 3.18 µs ± 38.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So here numba is a lot faster as expected. One thing to consider is that global numpy arrays do not behave in numba as you might expect:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html#numba-doesn-t-seem-to-care-when-i-modify-a-global-variable

It's usually better to pass in the data as I did in the example.

Your issue in the second case is that numba does not support `amin` at this time. See:

https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

You can see this if you pass `nopython=True` to `jit`. So in current versions of numba (0.44 or earlier at current), it will fall back to `objectmode` which often is no faster than not using numba and sometimes is slower since there is some call overhead.

Comment: Thanks Josh for the hint with `np.amin` and that `@jit(nonpython=True)` shows this! (+1). Concerning passing the data: You're right, that's important. In my actual implementation (can be found [here](https://github.com/CooleKarotte/timeSeries/blob/master/TWED/memoryEfficient_TWED.py)) I did this. Concerning question no. 2: Do you also have a clue why this might be?

Comment: Here the second [link](https://github.com/CooleKarotte/timeSeries/blob/master/TWED/multiInput_TWED.py) to the second implementation for the sake of completeness.