# Numba np.convolve really slow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, numba

I'm trying to speed up a piece of code convolving a 1D array (filter) over each column of a 2D array. Somehow, when I run it with numba's `njit`, I get a 7x slow down. My thoughts:

- Maybe column indexing is slowing it down, but switching to row indexing didn't affect performance
- Maybe slice indexing the results of the convolution is slow, but removing it didn't change anything
- I've checked that numba understands all the types properly

(tested on Windows 10, python 3.9.4 from conda, numpy 1.12.2, numba 0.53.1)

Can anyone tell me why this code is slow?

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

def f1(a1, filt):
    l2 = filt.size // 2
    res = np.empty(a1.shape)
    for i in range(a1.shape[1]):
        res[:, i] = np.convolve(a1[:, i], filt)[l2:-l2]
    return res

@njit
def f1_jit(a1, filt):
    l2 = filt.size // 2
    res = np.empty(a1.shape)
    for i in range(a1.shape[1]):
        res[:, i] = np.convolve(a1[:, i], filt)[l2:-l2]
    return res

a1 = np.random.random((6400, 1000))
filt = np.random.random((65))
f1(a1, filt)
f1_jit(a1, filt)

%timeit f1(a1, filt)     # 404 ms ± 19.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit f1_jit(a1, filt) # 2.8 s ± 66.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: It seems that performance is being slow down by majority of vectorised operations used within `@njit` decorator. I've never succeeded with that, although the reasons are not clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem comes from the Numba implementation of `np.convolve`. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4119). It turns out that **the current Numba implementation is much slower than the one of Numpy**  (version <=0.54.1 tested on Windows).

---

### Under the hood

On one hand, the [Numpy implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L748-L844) call `correlate` which itself performs a [dot product](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b235f9e701e14ed6f6f6dcba885f7986a833743f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1241) that *should* be implemented by the fast BLAS library available on your system. On the other hand, the [Numba implementation](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/3b1e4abd1b82ab5dc60f912ad43faa6e26cd87ba/numba/np/arraymath.py#L4010-L4031) calls [`_get_inner_prod`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/3b1e4abd1b82ab5dc60f912ad43faa6e26cd87ba/numba/np/arraymath.py#L3848) which use `np.dot` that *should* also use the same BLAS library (assuming a BLAS is detected which should be the case)...

That being said, there are multiple **issues related to the dot product**:

First of all, if the internal variable `_HAVE_BLAS` of `numba/np/arraymath.py` is manually disabled, Numba use a *fallback implementation* of the dot product supposed to be significantly slower. However, it turns out that **using the fallback dot product implementation used by `np.convolve` result in a 5 times faster execution** than with the BLAS wrapper on my machine! Using additionally the parameter `fastmath=True` in the `njit` Numba decorator results in an overall 8.7 times faster execution! Here is the testing code:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def npConvolve(a, b):
    return np.convolve(a, b)

@nb.njit('float64[:](float64[:], float64[:])')
def nbConvolveUncont(a, b):
    return np.convolve(a, b)

@nb.njit('float64[::1](float64[::1], float64[::1])')
def nbConvolveCont(a, b):
    return np.convolve(a, b)

a = np.random.random(6400)
b = np.random.random(65)
%timeit -n 100 npConvolve(a, b)
%timeit -n 100 nbConvolveUncont(a, b)
%timeit -n 100 nbConvolveCont(a, b)
```

Here are raw interesting results:

```
With _HAVE_BLAS=True (default):
126 µs ± 292 ns per loop
1.6 ms ± 21.3 µs per loop
1.6 ms ± 18.5 µs per loop

With _HAVE_BLAS=False:
125 µs ± 359 ns per loop
311 µs ± 1.18 µs per loop
268 µs ± 4.26 µs per loop

With _HAVE_BLAS=False and fastmath=True:
125 µs ± 757 ns per loop
327 µs ± 3.69 µs per loop
183 µs ± 654 ns per loop
```

Moreover, `np_convolve` of Numba internally *flip some array parameter* and then perform the dot product using a flipped array that have a non trivial stride (ie. not 1). Such **a non-trivial stride may have an impact on the dot product performance**. More generally, any transformation preventing the compiler to know that arrays are contiguous will certainly strongly impact the performances. Indeed, the following test shows the impact of working on a contiguous array with the dot product implementation of Numba:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def np_dot(a, b):
    return np.dot(a, b)

@nb.njit('float64(float64[::1], float64[::1])')
def nb_dot_cont(a, b):
    return np.dot(a, b)

@nb.njit('float64(float64[::1], float64[:])')
def nb_dot_stride(a, b):
    return np.dot(a, b)

v = np.random.random(128*1024)
%timeit -n 200 np_dot(v, v)         #  36.5 µs ±  4.9 µs per loop
%timeit -n 200 nb_dot_stride(v, v)  # 361.0 µs ± 17.1 µs per loop  (x10 !!!)
%timeit -n 200 nb_dot_cont(v, v)    #  34.1 µs ±  2.9 µs per loop
```

---

### Some general notes about Numpy and Numba

Note that Numba can hardly accelerate the Numpy calls when they work on pretty-big arrays since Numba *re-implement Numpy functions* mostly in Python and use a *JIT compiler* (LLVM-Lite) to speed them up, while Numpy is mostly implemented in plain-C (with a rather-slow Python wrapping code). The Numpy code uses low-level processor features like *SIMD instructions* to speed up a lot the execution of many functions. Both appear to use BLAS libraries known to be highly optimized. Numpy tends to be generally more optimized since Numpy is currently more mature than Numba: Numpy has much more contributors working since a longer time.

Comment: I learnt a lot from your answer, thanks! My thought process with this problem is that the python wrapping around fast numpy/BLAS routines in C is slow, so I was hoping numba could salvage some performance from there by removing the python interpreter in the hot loop. What would you recommend to improve the performance of this algorithm? The convolution is applying a filter on each column in the matrix.

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to wait for this issue to be solved in future Numba versions. However, you can alternatively write yourself a temporary workaround convolution function (with the parameter `fastmath=True`) that should be about as fast as the `_HAVE_BLAS=False + fastmath=True` case. This is a bit tedious to implement though. Moreover, you can *parallelize* the i-based loop using `njit` parameter `parallel=True` and `nb.prange` instead of the current `range`. Transposing `a1` should help to work on *contiguous arrays*. This should be significantly faster than the Numpy version.